# modifying quicksort in lisp to use an intermediate valuator filter

Tags: sorting, common-lisp, quicksort

I'm working on implementing quicksort that uses an intermediate valuator function;  not a test function, but a valuator which substitutes the indirect values the numbers otherwise represent in another context.

I'm having some trouble getting it to work in all cases and feel like I've hit a brick wall.  My main intention for this is sorting 3D triangles in a set by distance from camera (the array being one of indices to unique faces, and the valuator function does a lookup up of the mesh face of the given index and then returns the distance from camera), but for the sake of brevity I will use a much simpler example below.  Here is the quicksort-* code in Common Lisp:

```
(defun quicksort-* (arr lo hi &key (valuator #'identity))
  (declare (type (simple-array fixnum (*)) arr)
           (type fixnum lo hi)
           (type function valuator))
  (flet ((%partition (arr p r)
           (declare (type (simple-array fixnum (*)) arr)
                    (type fixnum p r))
           (let ((x (funcall valuator (aref arr p)))
                 (i (1- p))
                 (j (1+ r)))
             (loop do
                   (loop do
                         (decf j)
                         until (<= (funcall valuator (aref arr j)) x))
                   (loop do
                         (incf i)
                         until (>= (funcall valuator (aref arr i)) x))
                   (if (< i j)
                       (rotatef (aref arr i) (aref arr j))
                     (return-from %partition j))))))
    (when (< lo hi)
      (let ((p (%partition arr lo hi)))
        (quicksort arr lo p)
        (quicksort arr (1+ p) hi))))
  arr)
```

So what exactly would this do?

Given

```
(defparameter *names* #("Earl" "Dudley" "Chuck" "Bob" "Alice"))
```

and a list we want sorted, currently randomly scrambled as

```
(defparameter *nameindices* '(2 4 0 1 3))
```

Running quicksort-* on *nameindices* with a predicate function 'namevaluator':

```
(defun namevaluator (nameindex)
   (let ((sortednames (sort (copy-seq *names*) #'string>)))
      (position (aref *names* nameindex) sortednames :test #'string=)))
```

as such should yield #(4 3 2 1 0) to reflect the descendingly-sorted names, right?

```
CL-USER> (quicksort
           *nameindices*
            0 (1- (length *nameindices*))
            :valuator
            #'namevaluator)
#(0 1 2 3 4)
```

Hmm, nope.  But hey, at least it's still sorted, even if in reverse.

Well, certainly, changing #'string> to #'string< in the namevaluator function should yield #(4 3 2 1 0) then, right?  Well... no, this becomes the answer:

```
#(1 2 3 4 0)
```

Flipping the >= and <= signs around in the %partition function doesn't yield any better (and that's probably not too hot an idea anyway);  it still results in a case of one result being sorted, and the other being out-of-sequence.

I figured plugging in a funcall-predicate test in %partition where it originally simply evaluated the plain integer values for comparisons would have simply 'Just Worked'.  Indeed, with the default #'IDENTITY function as the valuator, it does:

```
(let ((random-numbers (coerce (loop repeat 30 collect (random 1000)) 'vector)))
   (quicksort-* random-numbers 0 (1- (length random-numbers))))

> #(29 91 121 130 191 228 250 382 392 406 443 468 468 480 535 555 576 597 598 604 635 646 646 685 712 721 724 764 849 860)
```

Maybe the answer is right under my nose but I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: The indentation is not correct... I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) Where you recursively call your function you use the name quicksort, but the name of the function is quicksort-*. Am I missing something?

(b) You pass the custom evaluator in the top-level call but do not do so in the recursive calls, so for those #'identity is operative. You might try a labels function for the recursion so you do not have to sweat restating the :valuator.

Comment: a) Just a typo;  copied the function to make changes, but didn't yet change it by the time I copied+pasted it for this post.    b)  Oh geez!!!  Yes, this probably was it.  How embarrassing!  After fixing that, I now properly get #(4 3 2 1 0), and back in my main project my 3D model is properly having its "FACE-DRAW-ORDER" array arranged.  I can't believe I lost an entire evening over such an oversight.  Thank you!

Comment: (1) It is a common mistake, which is why I suggested restructuring such that your top-level function accepted the customization and then a helper "labels" function holding the bulk of the processing would always see the customization and you could recur at will. (2) an evening lost to a typo? When it takes a whole evening, I know it's a typo. Come to think of it, you did, too. :)